# Effective method for reading large CSV files?

Tags: c++

I currently have 5 CSV files with about 45,000 records per each file. Whats the best method to go about this? Ive done I/O before, but never on this scale. Parse into a vector string?

Comment: What are your constraints?  Do you have enough memory?  How much if you don't know if it is enough?

Comment: Reading CSV files was discussed many times before on this site. have you looked at these methods and if so what was wrong with them?

Comment: What have you tried? Is it too slow? 45,000 records don't sound like a large data set needing any particular attention.

Comment: All im asking is what method is best for this range of records. Reading them all into a vector?

Comment: It also depends on how much fields each record has... At least you should provide a small code of what you tried so far.

Comment: i've loaded up 4 million records before from a csv, you don't need anything special

Answer (score 1):

Yes, read them into a `vector` would be reasonable.

The choice of storage does depend a little on what you are planning to do, and what the data is. If you know what the format of the data is, you may want to create a `struct`, and read the data into a more organised form. E.g. if the file is like this:

```
name, score, err

Mats, 89, 2.1%
Steve, 79, 8%
```

then you could have a structure like this:

```
struct Row
{
   string name;
   int    score;
   float  err;
}
```

As comments say, 45K lines is not very much, and it shouldn't cause any major problems unless you are running it on something with the computing capacity of a wrist-watch.

Comment: The CSV files have about 10 columns. Should i read in line by line for each element or split up the columns into different vectors?

Comment: Probably a good plan. I'd expect you can do that pretty easily.

Comment: Which ones a good plan, each line its own vector or each column its own vector?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the data later on. But I just wrote something that reads a CSV file into a `vector<vector<string>>`. Are you going to work on the data as columns, or as rows?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep doing what you are doing:  read all lines into a `Vector` of `string`s, a `Vector` of a `Vector` of `string`s, or a `Vector` of objects.  We are talking 200 to 500 MB RAM, and nowadays most computers have much more than that available.  From a processing time point of view, that's going to be 5 to 10 minutes in an average computer (depending on the amount of processing, of course).

If you run into any problem, ask a new question with more information.

Comment: Huh? 45K records take 200-500MB? That's 2-11KB per row. Sounds rather a lot. And 13ms per row to process it?

Comment: I just took a database table that has 48K records and exported it as CSV, and one of the fields is a "notification" (basically, the text to go into an email to be sent to clients of the website), and a total of 10 fields. The file is 216MB.

Comment: Reading that file, with a simple program that I just hacked up takes 0.4s.

Comment: @MatsPetersson  1)  He mentioned **5 files** of 45K rows each.  That's 0.4-2.2 KB/row.  I think my estimate is OK.  2)  Thanks for verifying my estimate.  I usually am right.  3)  I'm extremely conservative when I don't have any other information.  In this particular case, I assumed some DB access with each record.  Sorry if you think that in the absence of information optimistic estimates are the best.